# What's with the Wessen head shake?

Tags: film-techniques, production, grimm

In Grimm, what is the real-world reason for the Wessen head shake during woge? Is it to mask the morphing software?

This occurs in all episodes: Wessen characters snap their heads from side to side during woge transformation. In some (most, actually) werewolf movies for example, you can see clumsy morphing from human to wolf forms. It's time consuming and costly to do in production.

Since it occurs in Grimm so often, I'm wondering if they have a simplified morphing software of which it is necessary to mask intermediate stages of the frames.

The in-universe explanation is that it is mildly painful. I'm thinking this is a justification for a post-production reason.

Comment: Which episode is this from?

Comment: @Decypher I edited to explain.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it's for the viewer. It allows you to see the change and prepare for it. As weird as it is I feel it would be even more strange and less believable if the head was still and just changed in front of you eyes.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's to show that the change is voluntary, as the head shake doesn't happen with involuntary changes, most notably those that only grimms can see, but also those full-fledged ones that happen due to fear or some other strong emotion.

Notice that those involuntary woges are visually just as convincing as the voluntary ones, despite the lack of the shake, so I don't think that it's the morphing software issue.

Also, it comes quite in handy in rare occurrences when the woge fails, due to a character losing its Wessen properties, in which case we'd never see the attempt if there wasn't for the head shaking.